# can some one explain what this perl snippet involving regex is actually doing?

Tags: regex, perl

this code is supposed to give the extension and address of the file ,but how it is doing is not very clear.

```
($FileName, $TPath, $suffix) = fileparse($SourceFiles[$Index], '\.[^\.]*');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\.` matches a literal `.` and the `[^\.]*` matches everything until a `.` shows up. Essentially, it will match the extension.

But as @gaussblurinc said, it will also match a `.` by itself, try modifying it as follows:

```
qr(\.[^\.]+) # regex operator, catch dot (.) and everything behind it but not dot ([^\.])
```

Try experimenting [**here**](http://regex101.com/r/gU3bA9). I have already set it up a bit.

From documentation (fileparse):

```
my($filename, $directories, $suffix) = fileparse($path);
my($filename, $directories, $suffix) = fileparse($path, @suffixes);
my $filename                         = fileparse($path, @suffixes);
#If @suffixes are given each element is a pattern (either a string or
#a "qr//") matched against the end of the $filename. The matching
#portion is removed and becomes the $suffix.
         # On Unix returns ("baz", "/foo/bar/", ".txt")
         fileparse("/foo/bar/baz.txt", qr/\.[^.]*/);
```

so, I want to search through directories and output or perform some actions on images (resize them, for example with `convert`)

```
use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;
sub searchAndResizeImages{
    my ($searchDirectory) = shift;
    # use find or whatever you want, I prefer to use glob, oh
    # prepare images suffixes
    # for example, I know about png, gif, jpg, whatever else?
    my @suffixes = qw(png gif jpe?g);
    # and also try this: different output, but it can be more useful in your task
    # my @suffixes = map{".$_"}qw(png gif jpe?g);
    for (glob(File::Spec->catfile($searchDirectory, "*"))){
        if (!-d) { # if not directory
           my ($file, $path, $suffix) = fileparse($_,@suffixes);
           if ($suffix){
               print "file : $file\n";
               print "path : $path\n";
               print "suffix : $suffix\n";
               # do whatever you want here with images
           }
        }
    }

}

searchAndResizeImages('.');
```

Comment: I prefer to write qr() operator instead of strings, it seems more clear to understand **quoted_regex** instead of 'string'

Comment: @gaussblurinc, You are more than welcome to edit my answer if you have a good suggsestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

`fileparse` is a function from [`File::Basename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aBasename)

> - `my($filename, $directories, $suffix) = fileparse($path);`
> - `my($filename, $directories, $suffix) = fileparse($path, @suffixes);`
> - `my $filename                         = fileparse($path, @suffixes);`
>
>   The `fileparse()` routine divides a file path into its $directories, $filename and (optionally) the filename $suffix.
>
>   If `@suffixes` are given each element is a pattern (either a string or a `qr//`) matched against the end of the `$filename`. The matching portion is removed and becomes the `$suffix`.

In this case, the suffix is defined as everything after and including the last period `.`